# Select recursive in a CTE SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with unique KEY (UserID and Type)

```
UserID | Type | Column1 | Column2
----------------------------
 1     |   1  |  *NULL* |   1
 1     |   2  |   ABC   |  *NULL*
 1     |   3  |  *NULL* |   2
 2     |   1  |  *NULL* |   1
 2     |   2  |   CDE   |  *NULL*
 3     |   1  |  *NULL* |   3
 3     |   2  |   DTE   |  *NULL*
```

I am trying to build a query for searching all Users IDs contains:

```
(Type=1 AND Column2=1) AND (Type=3 AND Column2=2)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the results you are looking for.  And, your question has nothing to do with recursive CTEs.

Comment: Result must be UserID 1

Comment: @Paparazzi . . . As I read the data, UserId 1 *does* satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with recursive CTEs.  You can solve it with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select userid
from t
where (Type = 1 AND Column2 = 1) OR (Type = 3 AND Column2 = 2)
group by userid
having count(distinct type) = 2;
```

Comment: @JibinBalachandran There's no Type = 3 for userid 2, so it won't be returned.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Yeah multiple records satisfy that `WHERE` criteria with the `OR`, but only the userid that have records that meet both will satisfy the `HAVING` criteria.

Comment: Can you help me solution with ROW_NUMBER() for pagination

Comment: If you have another question, then ask it as another question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE(userid)  
AS
(
  SELECT userid
  FROM t
  WHERE (Type = 1 AND Column2 = 1)
)
SELECT userid 
FROM CTE  
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1 
              FROM CTE
              WHERE Type = 3 AND Column2 = 2 )
```